# junit-quickcheck - generating random trees keeping the depth finite

Tags: java, junit, quickcheck

I am practising junit-quickcheck.

I have prepared generators for the three sort components of a binary tree (`Node`, `Leaf`, `Empty`).

I wish to create random trees and verify properties upon them.

The generator for `Node`s picks further generators for its two branches based on certain probabilities.

However, I want the trees to stop growing at some time during each run. The probability of building a subtree that is a `Node` must decrease as the generation evolves.

I was hoping to be able to control the depth of the tree by using the `GenerationStatus`, but I cannot see exactly how.

Another hypothesis is to invoke method `configure()` of the next generator before `generate()`, but I haven't managed to do that yet.

What is the right way to achieve all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GenerationStatus#setValue(Key, Object)`](http://pholser.github.io/junit-quickcheck/site/0.7/junit-quickcheck-core/apidocs/com/pholser/junit/quickcheck/generator/GenerationStatus.html#setValue-com.pholser.junit.quickcheck.generator.GenerationStatus.Key-T-) to pass values between generators.

Here is an example I wrote that generates strictly decreasing lists of positive integers:

```
import com.pholser.junit.quickcheck.generator.GenerationStatus;
import com.pholser.junit.quickcheck.generator.Generator;
import com.pholser.junit.quickcheck.random.SourceOfRandomness;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListGenerator extends Generator<List<Integer>> {

    private static final int MAX_VALUE = 100;
    private static final GenerationStatus.Key<Integer> PREVIOUS_KEY = new GenerationStatus.Key<>("previous", Integer.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ListGenerator() {
        super((Class<List<Integer>>) (Class) List.class);
    }

    public List<Integer> generate(SourceOfRandomness sourceOfRandomness, GenerationStatus generationStatus) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        int previous = generationStatus.valueOf(PREVIOUS_KEY).orElse(MAX_VALUE);
        int current = sourceOfRandomness.nextInt(previous);

        if (current > 0) {
            result.add(current);

            generationStatus.setValue(PREVIOUS_KEY, current);
            Generator<List<Integer>> listGen = gen().make(ListGenerator.class);
            result.addAll(listGen.generate(sourceOfRandomness, generationStatus));
            generationStatus.setValue(PREVIOUS_KEY, null);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you generate a (bounded) list of values to put into the tree, and compose the tree from these values. Then you know for sure that the structure is bounded.

You might want to take care to balance the tree in case that simply calling `add` sequentially might produce a highly unbalanced tree, but this depends on your tree implementation.

Similarly for Helder-Pereira's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41896765/364401), there's no need for recursive generators: I would generate a list of integers and sort the list.